# How Am I Wrong? Geometric Algebra Question

Tags: geometric-algebras, outer-product

I'm currently teaching myself Geometric Algebra out of the textbook *Geometric Algebra for Physicists*, and there's an example I get wrong. In the example, they show that $(\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b})^2=-\mathbf{a}^{2}\mathbf{b}^2sin^2{θ}$

---

My Work:

$(a \wedge b)^2 = (a\wedge b)(a \wedge b) = (a\wedge b)(-b \wedge a) = (ab - a \cdot b)(-ba + a\cdot b)= $

$= a^2 b^2 - (a\cdot b)^2 + a\cdot b(ab - ab)$

$= a^2 b^2 - (a\cdot b)^2$

$= a^2 b^2 - (|a||b| \cos(\theta))^2$

$=  a^2 b^2 -  a^2 b^2 \cos^2(\theta)$

$= a^2b^2(1 - \cos^2(\theta))$

$= a^2b^2 \sin^2(\theta)$

---

I almost get the right answer, but keep getting the negative of the book's answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all ! It seems to me that you start with two vectors, denoted in bold. Okay. But then you drop the bold notation and you introduce a quantity like $ab$. Is that a tensor? Is it a scalar ? And what is the outer product squared? Does it involve the inner product, or is it a tensor? And below in the comments you introduce a $*$ product, which confuses things even more.

Comment: @M.Wind these objects and products are from Geometric Algebra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra

Comment: It appears to be some sort of elementary matrix calculations (linear algebra). However, the notation is so compact, that there is no distinction between scalars, vectors and tensors. You can not see whether a calculation step involves summation over indices. There is no unit matrix. No wonder the OP is confused !

Comment: @M.Wind I would suggest reading a bit on the subject. the objects involved are not what you suggest. These are called multivectors. They are not simply scalars, vectors or tensors. They are a combination. There is no summation over indices in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first to second row:
$(ab- a\cdot b)(-ba + a \cdot b)  \\=-abba+(a \cdot b)ab+(a \cdot b)ba-(a \cdot b)^2 \\=-a^2 b^2 +(a \cdot b)(ab+ba) -(a \cdot b)^2
\\= -a^2 b^2+2(a \cdot b)^2-(a \cdot b)^2
\\=-a^2 b^2 +(a \cdot b)^2$

which gives you the overall minus sign that you were after.

Comment: But $\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}=-\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}$ right?

Comment: No. $ab+ba=2(a \cdot b)$, because $ab = a\cdot b + a \wedge b$, and $a \cdot b = b \cdot a, a\wedge b = -b \wedge a$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra

Comment: Okay, I just solved it on my own as well, and here is my work:
$-\mathbf{a}^2\mathbf{b}^2-(\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b})^2+(\mathbf{a}*\mathbf{b})(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a})$
Becomes:
$-\mathbf{a}^2\mathbf{b}^2-(\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b})^2+(\mathbf{a}*\mathbf{b})(2\mathbf{a}*\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b}\wedge\mathbf{a})$
Becomes
$-\mathbf{a}^2\mathbf{b}^2-(\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b})^2+(\mathbf{a}*\mathbf{b})(2\mathbf{a}*\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\wedge\mathbf{b})$
Which simplifies to your answer.